# Django ModelForm: adding an alias to a field

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I have a (GoogleAppEngine) Django ModelForm:

```
class A(db.Model):
  a = db.StringProperty()

class MyAForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = A
```

This creates a form which has one string field `a`. On my form I'd like to call this something else, say `b`. So I'd like a form with a field called `b` and when the form is POSTed we create a new A entity with the `a` property filled with the `b`-value.

Is there a neat way to do the plumbing for this?

(p.s. I don't want to change the underlying model)

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear what you mean when you say you want to 'call' the field something else on your form. Do you mean the label? That's easy to do :

```
class MyAForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  a = forms.CharField(label='b')
  class Meta:
    model = A
```

If you want to change the underlying HTML ID, you can do that via the widget:

```
  a = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'b'}))
```

I don't think it's possible to change the actual field's HTML name, but I can't think of any reason you'd want to do this.

Comment: I want to be able to do the following (assuming that I've set the right view):

`curl -d"b=my_b_string" http://domain.com/api/A`

This creates a new A(a='my_b_string').

Comment: If you have two forms on the same page, where they both contain the name field.  This is the scenario I've run into, where I want to alias one of them off, so the request.POST when passed into the form will retrieve the correct variables.

Comment: @Richard: That's what form prefixes are for: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

Answer (score 0):

```
class A(db.Model):
    a=db.StringProperty(verbose_name='b')
```

Comment: "(p.s. I don't want to change the underlying model)"

Answer (score 0):

the other way should be redefining the label of the field:

```
class MyAForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = A

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['a'].label = 'something'
```